# How do I set a textbox text color when it's being edited

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I'm working with java and I have a text box which I read data from a database into. So for example, the name "John" loads into the text box. I have the code

```
<input class="classText" name="fName" id="fname1" type="text" value=""/><br />
```

but what I'm wanting to do is keep the word that's loaded into the textbox black and change the color to blue when I try to enter text into that text box. So for example, 
The word "john" is loaded in the text box...I delete the word John and type in Max. Max should be blue.

Hope that's not too confusing. Any help?

Comment: You mean like http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/t8TGk/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onkeypress` event

```
 <input class="classText" name="fName" id="fname1" type="text" value="" onkeypress="changeColour(this)"/><br />
```

and define function

```
<script>
function changeColour(e)
{
  e.style.color='blue'
}
</script>
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CJPKY/2/)
Or better assign some class on key press

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the fiddle doesn't work either. It's not changing anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use css for styling.

```
#fname1:focus{color:blue}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BC5RP/

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your backend is Java is irrelevant here - you're dealing with the UI only.
There are several approaches to this. The one [on this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v8d6p/) uses JQuery's on(input).

```
$('.classText').on('input', function() {
$(this).addClass('changed');
});
```